# How can I dynamically place an image of same size and position over an another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically place an image of same size and position over an another div, but I am unable to make it work.

Here is my current attempt.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  >
 $(document).ready(function() {
var div = document.getElementById("im");
var canvas = document.getElementById("img");

canvas.height = div.offsetHeight ;
canvas.width  = div.offsetWidth ;
canvas.offsetTop = div.offsetTop;
canvas.offsetLeft  = div.offsetLeft;


 });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>
<div id="im">
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div><img id="img" src="axz.png" style="position:  absolute; z-index:100; border:dotted thick; "   />
<div   class="t">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this example I made for you.

Is this what you want?

Updated:

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/Byzn8/1/

Comment: I wanted that this google image comes right on top of the red DIV element :)

Comment: Ok, mm is it necessary to be "over" the div or replace the html inside the div with the image? :-)